# how to store more variables in registers with limited number of cpu registers

Tags: cpu, register

In an interview i was asked a question whether we can store 5 variables in the cpu registers if the processor has only 4 cpu registers. I confidently gave answer NO, then the interviewer gave me some weird look.

My question is that is it possible to store more variables in cpu registers than the actual number of cpu registers, if register and variable sizes are
1. same
2. not same

Comment: It depends of the length of the registers and values you have to store. If a portion of a register is enough to store one value and the leftover is enought for another, then we can do really better than 1:1.

Comment: @GombaiSándor Edited question

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can:

- if the variables are smaller than the registers. In x86 there are even registers that 'look' into others - AX = AH + AL, etc
- (exotic) if mentioned 4 registers are general-purpose registers and veriable sizes are the same as registers - there's probably also an instruction pointer register, so do a jump to the fifth variable like an address - and you'll have all 5 stored in registers for some period of time before the crash